# Invalid ui node error when indicating in uipath studio

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I have started using uipath for the past two days. I am reading from an excel sheet and loading to a web page and progress has been good.

I am stuck on the following scenario. I have a bs-datepicker that is used to enter dates. I have been able to get the date from the data in the sheet, separate the day,month & year parts. I have automated the selection of the month and year I have no issues.

The day is where the issue is. The control looks like the below,

[image]

On using the inspect tool on chrome, i see this for the 29th of May,

> `<td role="gridcell" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""><span bsdatepickerdaydecorator="" class="">29</span></td>`

I see the following for 29th of April,

> `<td role="gridcell" class="ng-star-inserted"><span bsdatepickerdaydecorator="" class="is-other-month">29</span></td>`

As you can see one difference between the two is that the span class is an empty string for 29th May which i am guessing is the error when i am getting when attempting to indicate on screen 29th of May,

[image]

In fact i get that same error when trying to indicate all elements for the active month, which is May in this case but no errors when indicating for the last month which is April.

Any tips on how i can get around this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers. What i ended up doing is using a try catch with a *selector not found exception.*

So the following will fall in the *try*,

```
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Add Employee | *' />
<webctrl aaname='{{FromDay}}' tag='SPAN' class='' parentclass='ng-star-inserted' />
```

And in the *Catch*,

```
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Add Employee | *' />  
<webctrl  aaname='{{FromDay}}' tag='SPAN' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try switching between the UiFrameworks when grabbing your selectors:

[Switching between Ui Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHBB.png)

There is a high chance of it working with "Active Accessibility", since it's suited for legacy apps or apps that do not respond to the Default framework. Switch between all 3 to make sure.

If that doesn't work, you can try to grab the selector by navigating to the visual tree and manually going through all the nodes until you find your element.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Dynamic selector because it seems that the selector changes when you change the month.
https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/dynamic-selectors

Or another option, you could use the "Click text" activity to click on the number of the month you need.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change the node selector in uipath studio from class='is-other-month' to class='*'